# What does "male" mean in an answer?

Tags: meaning, english-to-german

What's the meaning of *male* in this expression?

> Antwort: "Nein, heute nachmittag *male* ich. Danke."

Comment: Please add context. I fear the existing answers may not fit, at least not to "slang" (title prior to edit), and not to the tag english-to-german. What was the question this answer was given to? Did you hear it, did you read it?

Comment: Did you look up the word in a dictionary? Could you please edit your question and add, why the dictionary entries were not satisfying? And could you also add, why you used the tag _english-to-german_? Based on your original question and the current edits, I would assume, it is rather a _german-to-english_ request...

Comment: **malen** is no slang, so the change of title is all justified

Answer (score 2):

It means "painting" in this context.

> No, this afternoon I'm painting. Thanks.

*male* is the conjugated form of *[malen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/malen)*.

Comment: @Björn: did you mean the English form? I think the translation *This afternoon I'm painting* is fine. *I'll be painting* is fine too, but the other one is good enough, in speech.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: you're absolutely right about the verb, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The verb [*malen*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/malen) means *to draw* or *to paint*. In the sentence

> Heute Nachmittag *male* ich.

you have the conjugated form, *male*, without a terminating *n*. (Also notice that *Nachmittag* beginns with a capital letter, because it is a noun.) The seven conjugated forms of *malen* are:

> **singular**
>
> - ich male → I paint
> - du malst → you paint
> - er/sie/es malt → he/she/it paints
>
> **plural**
>
> - wir malen → we paint
> - ihr malt → you paint
> - sie malen → they paint
>
> **honorific (singular or plural)**
>
> - Sie malen → you paint

Comment: Not to forget the polite form of "you": Sie (capital 'S') malen -> you paint.

Comment: @mic: Ist die distanzierte Form der zweiten Person Singular nicht immer identisch mit der dritten Plural?

Answer (score 0):

Without more context this can be anything between painting the walls of a newly rented appartement (more in the colloqquial sense, since *streichen* would be the more appropriate verb) to creating something like a painting or just some powerpoint slides.

The generic meaning is *creating something coloured*.